# How is 0x000000 syntactically valid as a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, three.js

I'm learning THREE.js and when specifying object's colours you use `0x` with a hex value on the end. What does this mean?

Are they valid variable names?

How do they work?

I thought something starting with a number couldn't be a variable?

Comment: Are you sure it's used as a variable? Looks more like a literal value (like `123` or `"foo"`), something that you can *assign* to a variable.

Comment: The title says "valid as a value", but the question body says "valid variable names". Which is it?

Comment: The question title asks if it is valid as a *value* and the answer is yes, but then you ask about them being valid as *variable names* in the body of the question, and the answer to that is no. Variables and values are very, very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use hexadecimal representation for value literals.
From [MDN - Numeric Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Numeric_literals):

> #### Hexadecimal
>
> Hexadecimal number syntax uses a leading zero followed by a lowercase or uppercase Latin letter "X" (0x or 0X). If the digits after 0x are outside the range (0123456789ABCDEF),  the following SyntaxError is thrown: "Identifier starts immediately after numeric literal".
>
> ```
> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF // 295147905179352830000
> 0x123456789ABCDEF   // 81985529216486900
> 0XA                 // 10
> ```

You can also find a grammar here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3
(It is interesting to note that octal literal are not included here because they are not used in [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). The grammar is specified under [B.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1))

Answer (score 4):

> Are they valid variable names?

No. They are integer (number) literals. Instead of `0x000000` you could've written `0`, and instead of `0x10` you could write `16`.

Answer (score 3):

This is something javascript inherited from C and even earlier.

Ordinary numeric decimal constants look like this:

```
x = 42
```

Back in the old days (and even now in certain cases) it was useful to be able to specify constants in octal form; an extra leading 0 indicates this:

```
x = 052  /* 42 */
```

When hexadecimal constants started to become a useful thing, they were shoehorned in as having a leading 0x (which would have been a syntax error before):

```
x = 0x2a /* 42 */
```

and newer versions of javascript now support binary constants (0b) and more explicit octal constants (0o):

```
x = 0b101010 /* 42 */
x = 0o52 /* 42 */
```

None of these forms are valid variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Each color is a value (not a variable), so:

Black is 0, which is represented in hexadecimal form as 0x000000.

Answer (score 1):

> 0x with a hex value on the end. What does this mean?

These mean that they are [hexadecimal numbers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Numeric_literals)

> Are they valid variable names?

Which ones? If you are saying 0X then they are hexadecimal else please specify